# Point to pixel conversion

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-2d

On Mac OS X, I need to convert a point measurement to pixel measurement.

The formula which I know is

```
pixel   = point * resolution (in terms of dpi) / 72
```

I have few measurements which I want to convert to pixels. Although reverse cases would also be possible.

How to do this in Cocoa or Quartz?
Does it depend on axis? Means would 5 pixels in Y-axis would be same as 5 pixels in X-axis in terms of points? Or is it safe to assume that resolution is same for both X and Y axis?

Please note that I do not want to make any assumption about resolution.

Comment: How did you end up with measurements in points?

Comment: Measurement in points is coming as a user input. User can specify length in points, pixels, inches, mms and cms.

Comment: Also, font size is in points. Sometimes, you may need to convert it into pixel to draw a rectangle where you may need pixel.

Comment: ok just checking that you realise font size in pts is meaningless as pixels (two 12pt fonts are not the same size)

Comment: Also you should forget about getting the screen resolution (and your formula), it doesn't sound like what you really want is to convert points to pixels. That is only useful if you want the user to specify "I need to draw this 3cm high, whatever the screen/display -ie even on a giant billboard make it exactly 3cm" - this is difficult and rarely what is needed. Otherwise just pick an arbitrary scale.. a good one is 1 point = 1 quartz unit

Answer (score 6):

You probably don't want to convert anything to pixels. OS X now works in *points*; so for example when you draw a rectangle you are giving its dimensions in points, not pixels.

A OS X Quartz point is related to, but not the same as, a *(computer) printing point* - the two used to be the same, 72 points = 1". However WYSIWYG has become "some scale of" and 72 points (note not pixels) on screen is not a physical inch as screen pixel densities have increased. However 72 points is still an "abstract" inch.

In OS X you draw in points, the OS takes care of mapping those points to the physical pixels on the screen; which roughly translates to screens up to a certain density being treated as 72ppi (pixels/inch) or 1 pixel/point, and higher density screens being treated as 144ppi or 2 pixel/point - for example these are the ppi assigned to standard and Retina screenshots.

If you *really, really* need to know what a point translates to in pixels you can find out, but this changes depending on what screen a window is on.

For details of all of this you can start with [Points Don’t Correspond to Pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW1) and then read the rest of the *High Resolution Guidelines for OS X* that reference is part of. How to find point to backing store mapping, if you *really, really* need to know, is covered.

HTH

Comment: The "abstract" inch can be 50% from a physical inch.    The 'Text size 14' in Finder measures 2.47mm high on my MBP, which would make it a 7 point physical font.  The "Points Don't Correspond to Pixels" page says "on a high-resolution display, there are four onscreen pixels for each point," indicating a 4:1 correspondence in hi-res, and 1:1 correspondence in standard res.

Answer (score 2):

There is an opportunity for confusion when your user specifies a length in 'points' as to whether they mean typography points of size 1/72" or lenghts compared to Mac UI points, which vary with the display resolution.

In Mac OS, "points" *are* pixels, unless you are in high resolution mode, in which case points are 2x2 pixels.  The  "[Points Don't Correspond to Pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH4-SW1)" page says "on a high-resolution display, there are four onscreen pixels for each point," indicating a 4:1 correspondence in hi-res, and 1:1 correspondence in standard res.   It also notes:

> Note: The term points has its origin in the print industry, which defines 72 points as to equal 1 inch in physical space. When used in reference to high resolution in OS X, points in user space do not have any relation to measurements in the physical world.

To convert a typographer's point size to something physically the same size on a Mac screen in Mac points, your formula is exactly correct.  You might rename 'pixel' to Mac points:

```
MacPoints = (TypesettersPoints/72)*ResolutionInDotsPerInch
```

Answer (score 1):

Best to stick with points. 
First you would need to know where the point is coming from. Views, Windows and Screens all have their own coordinate systems. 
You would need to do several things to translate this to the pixel grid of a given screen.

First you need to convert your point to the screen coordinates. 
Then to coordinates of pixel grid of the screen.

You will also need to find out the current display properties to know if it's a retina display or not. ( makes a big difference.)

All of the methods are in NSView, NSWindow, NSScreen. 
All of the functions are part of Quartz Display services. You will need ones for CGDisplay you might need ones for CGWindow.

You will also need to have your app observe notifications for display configuration changes and figure out the hard part, when a point is in a coordinate space that overlaps two screens.

I leave it to you to do the rest and decide if you really need this.